Issue with Line and Clustered column chart (Power BI)
I have a problem with a visual on power BI, a graph is not showing the correct information. The visual is taking the data from different sources, one column is "ADDED M&Y", that has the following values ["2024;02" , "2024;03" , "2024;04"] and other column, "Archived M&Y" that has the values ["2024;02" , "2024;03" , "2024;04"]. So the graph is counting the values for each date on each column and should contrast each of them per month. I also want to have a line that crosses the graph that would be the pending cases (the difference between the added and the archived).
Should look like the image on the left, but i´m getting the one in the right (the one in the left is made by a PivotTable that is not part of the table so the page filters don't apply):

I cant figure out how to make it work. Please feel free to ask any question, and thanks in advance
I tried creating a different table with only the dates and counting the values for each one but does not seem to work
